# Como cambiar el width de un input con primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

Tengo un login bastante sencillo, pero no logro que el width del input del email se acomode al tamaño de la card. Tambien intente con css y nada.

Estoy usando primeng con primeflex. Les agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

```
<div class="p-grid custom-vertical-center">
  <app-card class="custom-card">
    <div appCardHeader>
      <h2 class="p-text-center p-mb-5">LOGIN</h2>
    </div>
    <div appCardContent>
      <div class="login-panel">
        <span class="p-input-icon-left p-mb-2">
          <i class="pi pi-user"></i>
          <input id="email" style="width: 100%;" type="email" pInputText class="w-full" placeholder="Email"
            formControlName="email" />
        </span>

        <p-password id="password" type="password" [feedback]="false" placeholder="Contraseña"
          styleClass="p-password p-component p-inputwrapper p-input-icon-right p-mb-4" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
          [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" [toggleMask]="true" formControlName="password"></p-password>

        <button routerLink="/dashboard" pButton pRipple label="Ingresar" class="w-full p-mb-5"
          [style]="{'width':'100%'}"></button>

        <div class="login-links p-text-center">
          <a routerLink="/recuperar">Recuperar Contraseña</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-card>
</div>
```

Les dejo como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba usando `styleClass="wid100"`

Comment: @René gracias por responder, no tampoco funciona.

Comment: Usando el mismo que en password? `[style]="{'width':'100%'}"` o usando `styleClass="w-full"` o en lugar de `w-full` usando `max-w-full`

Comment: @René Sigue sin funcionar, no entiendo porq no aplica el estilo.

Comment: Y probando en el span?